# mitmproxy: shortcut for undoing edit

Tags: python, mitmproxy

new user of mitmproxy here. I've figured out how to edit a request and replay it, and I'm wondering how to undo my edit.

More specifically, I go to a request's flow, hit 'e', then '8' to edit the request headers. Then I press 'd' to delete one of the headers. What do I press to undo this change? 'u' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to revoke changes to a flow, but not while editing. In your case, 'e' -> '8' -> 'd' headers, now press 'q' to go back to the flow -> press 'V' to revoke changes to the flow.